# Como mudar o foco de um TextBox para o próximo?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando mudar o foco do campo após o usuário escrever 2 dígitos. A validação está ok, porém ainda não encontrei um método para conseguir mudar de foco.

OBS: É um método dinâmico usado para vários campos, então eu não posso especificar na mão qual o controle que eu quero o foco.

Segue minha tentativa:

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var campo = (TextBox) sender;

        if(campo.Text.Length == 2)
        {
            var campoSeguinte = Controls.Find("txtP1N19", true); 
            // Não achei um "seletor" para encontrar o proximo item pelo TabIndex ai 
            // busquei pelo nome para testar.

            Controls[0].Text = "11"; // Com o campo encontrado tentei interagir
            Controls[0].Focus();
            Controls[0].Select();               
            Controls[0].Update();

            // Mas dessa forma o campo encontrado não ficou com o valor 11 e nem com foco. 
            // Não aconteceu nada apesar de debugando eu vir que passou por todo o trecho

        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o método `SelectNextControl()` do container contendo o conjunto de controles em questão.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control p;
    p = ((Button) sender).Parent;
    p.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```

Fonte: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Esse (Button) sender está correto? Não entendi o uso dele!

Comment: Troquei pra (TextBox) e funcionou. Muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @JoaoPaulo este exemplo foi tirado do artigo na MSDN. A assinatura padrão do método `_Click()` automaticamente implementa o objeto `sender` - você pode então trocar para o valor que necessitar.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Fico feliz em ler isso, é um prazer ajudar. =)

Answer (score 0):

***Código:***

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
    }
}
```

***Referência:*** [Control.KeyUp Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx)